# How to Recursively Parse Substrings Inside of Parentheses

Tags: java, parsing, lisp, interpreter

I'm writing a LISP interpreter, in Java, and I'm trying to create a function that can recursively and dynamically evaluate all of the arguments inside of a set of parentheses into a single value. It needs to solve any combination of input parameters needing to be evaluated. For example,  `+ 2 3` means no parameters need to be solved, `+ (+ 1 2) (+ 1 2)` means both parameters need to be solved, `+ 1 (+ 1 2)` means only the second parameter needs to be solved, and `+ (+ 1 2) 1` means only the first parameter needs to be solved. In this, I'm assuming that all of the operations that can be performed will only have 2 parameters (+, -, *, /, etc)

I have included my snippet of what already works. My function can solve down the input if either both parameters need to be solved, or if neither of them need to be solved. My issue is that I can't figure out a way how to check if only one parameter needs to be solved. Note: I'm returning the results as strings on purpose.

```
public String test(String input) { //input comes in without outter-most parentheses

        String param1, param2;
        if (input.indexOf('(') != -1) { //'(' exists somewhere in the string

            int param1Start = input.indexOf('(');
            int iter = param1Start + 1;
            int c = 1;
            while (c != 0) { //loop through the string until the matching close parentheses is found
                if (input.charAt(iter) == '(')
                    c++;
                if (input.charAt(iter) == ')')
                    c--;
                iter++;
            }
            String subs1 = input.substring(param1Start + 1, iter - 1);

            param1 = test(subs1); //further evaluate the first parameter

            int param2Start = iter + 1;
            iter = param2Start + 1;
            c = 1;
            while (c != 0) { //loop through the string until the matching close parentheses is found
                if (input.charAt(iter) == '(')
                    c++;
                if (input.charAt(iter) == ')')
                    c--;
                iter++;
            }
            String subs2 = input.substring(param2Start + 1, iter - 1);
            param2 = test(subs2); //further evaluate the second parameter
        } else { //no parentheses left in string, solving time
            String[] splitter = input.split(" ", 3);

            return Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(splitter[1]) + Integer.parseInt(splitter[2]));
        }
        return Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(param1) + Integer.parseInt(param2));


    }
```

Can anyone find a way to check if only one parameter needs to be evaluated? Or post a better Java solution?

Comment: *Or post a better solution than mine.* [Ok.](https://clojure.org/)

Comment: is this a valid input `+ ( + (+ 1 2) 2) (+ 1 2) ?`

Comment: @carlossalzar yes it should be for the end result. What I have will not work on that, though

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I meant an implemented solution in Java...

Comment: @Bionic_Beadle Clojure is a lisp dialect written in Java.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch okay sure, but I need a solution as a function that I can utilize in my existing program

Comment: But `+` is a variable so it needs to be resolved? The simplest way is to evaluate each part regardless and rather have the evaluator return the argument when the value is a self evaluating value, like a number.

Comment: Also, usually you parse the string into a structure and that structure is what gets evaluated. You seem to be doing both in one go. It's much better splitting those two up.

Comment: @Sylwester how would I split those two up?

Comment: I would not recommend to ever merge parsing and evaluation in a single step. Read your s-expressions into a tree representation first, then evaluate your trees easily.